# python function variables and namespaces

Tags: python

why does this code

```
def f(sum, l=[]):
    l.append(sum)
    print(l)

f(10)
f(10)
```

return

```
[10]
[10, 10]
```

I cannon understand why shouldn't it return

```
[10]
[10]
```

Comment: You're setting l = [] to l = [10], so when you re-run the function it appends 10 to l = [10] thus giving you l = [10,10]

Comment: As List is mutable object above behaviour is observed, similar behaviour is not observed in immutable objects chek https://pythonsimplified.com/mutability-immutability-in-python/